# How to import PyCrypto inside App Engine development server (OS X)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pycrypto

My `app.yaml` include this lines:

```
libraries:
- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6"
```

I have the correct version of PyCrypto:

```
$ python
>>> import Crypto
>>> Crypto.__version__
'2.6'
```

But when I try evaluate `import Crypto` in GAE Development SDK interactive console, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/request_handler.py", line 225, in handle_interactive_request
    exec(compiled_code, self._command_globals)
  File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Crypto
```

Answer (score 1):

Because pycrypto includes native compiled code, you need to install that yourself for your Python installation. Assuming you have pip installed:

```
pip install pycrypto
```