# Python pycrypto disables logging - google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging, pycrypto

I am using python with google app engine. Working on Macbook air 2012 with python 2.7.

The problem I have is:

```
import logging

logging.info("test") # this works before importing crypto

import Crypto

logging.info("test2") # this one does not after importing crypto
```

How does crypto change logging and how can I fix it so that I can use logging normally again in my python app?

Update1:

It seems that some python errors are also not displayed in the logging from app engine, as well as correct python code also giving a '500 internal server error' which is only visible in a browser console when testing the app in localhost.

Update2:

I have completely disabled any imports of Python Crypto ( which is provide by Google App Engine ), and now my logging works correctly, displaying all my own testing logging lines and python errors. This of course does not solve the problem as I need the Crypto module. Using Crypto in this case blocks the ability to test any code because you can not see errors in the logging.

Update3:

To be clear, I have included the crypto library in app.yaml exactly as instructed by Google App Engine docs. The crypto library itself works fine, the problem is that it breaks logging in my python app engine app.

Comment: What crypto package are you using? The most likely one needs a capital C https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto. There is no reason for it to break anything. Is this seen on the dev or prod server?

Comment: I am using the one google app engine provides. This is happening on the dev server

Comment: That package still needs a capital C. I just tested and it worked for me. More code and your setup would help.

Comment: Ok will test and report back

Comment: Yes, am using import Crypto with capital C. Problem persists

Comment: If you see the same results with Capital over lower case then there is something else wrong here. The lowercase should have been throwing errors. Try re-installing the pycrypto package and provide the full logs.

Comment: The crypto package comes from Google App Engine I can't reinstall it. I have already reinstall the appenginelauncher, have deleted the app, have deleted the datastore and tried again after every try but with no luck.

The log only displays get messages from images and html content being loaded from static resources.

Comment: Pycrypto is not installed as part of the SDK. You need to install it manually http://stackoverflow.com/a/29522062/3877822. You do not need to include it with the deployment as it is installed on the Prod servers.

Comment: @Ryan I have reinstalled pycrypto but the problem persists. One error during installing I notice is that something with '_counter' seems messed up, could that have something to do with it?

Otherwise, I have as mentioned in the updated question, tried disabling the Crypto import and then everything works fine. With the import included the problem persists.