# Python logging inconsistent - google-app-engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging

I'm using logging in python to see if some code was executed.

Right now logging is not always consistently putting lines in the log, for `logging.info` calls that are placed globally ( not within a function ).

Sometimes `logging.info('test')` is placed in the log, and sometimes its not.

What could be the cause of this?

I have verified that the logging module was not modified in anyway. The only thing that is happening in my code with logging is:

```
import logging
logging.info('test')
logging.info('test2')
```

Some of the times I run my code the logging lines are displayed, and sometimes only the first one. I have found out that logging behaves unpredictably around an import from Crypto.

```
logging.info('This one works sometimes')
import Crypto.Hash
logging.info('This does not work, only when I create an error intentionally')
```

Has anyone experienced this strange behaviour in logging with App Engine, and was it too related to Crypto import or to something else? How did you fix it?

Update:

This has become a duplicate question - [Python Crypto breaks logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32562070/python-crypto-disables-logging)

Comment: show your app.yaml - have you included pycrypto there? How is this any different to the last time you asked this exact same question?

Comment: and you would not need to include it in your project to deploy, the point of adding it to the app.yaml is so it's available to your app. Show your app.yaml!

Comment: Hi, Just to let you know, this seems to be a copy of an earlier question you asked (unless I'm missing something). If you have new information on that earlier question, you should consider editing that question, not creating a new question altogether :)

Comment: Yes, my mistake. To answer about the yaml, I have included crypto and the library itself is working.

Comment: Guys, if the question is a sure duplicate, just vote to close it as duplicate, or flag it if you cannot vote to close

Comment: @TimCastelijns Already updated my question with a link to the duplicate. The discussion is held there now.

Comment: I saw that, but it is important that it gets closed as duplicate so future visitors will know to look there instead of here

Comment: @TimCastelijns How do I close it? Just delete the question?

Comment: Just vote to close it as duplicate, or flag it if you cannot vote to close. The options to do that are located under the question, next to delete and edit

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yes, flagged this question to have it removed.

Comment: @TimCastelijns I didn't vote to close it as a dupe because I was under the impression the dupe target needs an answer (except on meta)... is it different if both Qs are from the same user? Or am I just plain wrong here?

Comment: @Patrice you can close dupes with no answer from the same user

Comment: @timCastelijns I will remember that for the future :). In the meantime my vote is cast here. Thanks!